# React navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I currently have two screens that are linked via a `TabBarNavigator`:

**ScreenA**: Upon pressing a button, I trigger this function `this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {data: 'test'}` whereupon `{data: 'test'}` is the `params`.

**ScreenB**: The navigation to this page works as expected. However, I am unable to access the params object - even though I can see it in the Navigation Dispatch log in my console.

I've looked at the react-navigation API, especially on their [link about navigation props](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop) but to no avail. Any suggestions on how I can programmatically access the `params` on ScreenB?

Edits:

1. My current navigation setup is:

   - StackNavigator

     - Other scene
     - DrawerNavigator

       - Another scene
       - TabBarNavigator

         - **SceneA**
         - **SceneB**
2. When on SceneB, the output of `console.log(this.props.navigation.state)` is `{key: "SceneB", routeName: "SceneB"}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `ScreenB` component, you should be able to access the `params` that were passed by using `this.props.navigation.state.params`. Kinda long, huh?

So in your case you can do:

`console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.data` and you will see `test`!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! It kind of worked. When I tried it with a StackNavigator - it worked perfectly. However, with the TabBarNavigator - I got `undefined` for that console.log.

Comment: Hmm, let's see. Is your TabBarNavigator nested inside the StackNavigator?

Comment: Yep. Stack > Drawer > TabBar

Comment: And are you still trying to access the props from `ScreenB` (which I assume is navigated to by the StackNavigator) from the screen in the TabNavigator?

Comment: That is correct - although i'm not sure which Navigator is really in charge. Both `ScreenA` and `ScreenB` are in TabNavigator

Comment: I added my current navigation setup on my post

Comment: Hmmm, well isn't that strange. In ScreenB, what is the result of just `this.props.navigation.state`?

Comment: `{key: "SceneB", routeName: "SceneB"}`

Comment: Hmm, this that is very strange. Now I'm not sure. It almost sounds like a bug to be honest. If you really are calling `this.props.navigation.navigate` on the TabBarNavigation prop, it should be merging the params into the TabBarNavigation state, not the StackNavigator state. Well, if you're real desperate, you can pass down the state from StackNavigator with `screenProps` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Navigator-Props

Comment: I'm starting to think it is a bug with the DrawerNavigator as well (there was difficulty in attempting redux). So from StackNavigator to DrawerNavigator - would I just pass `screenProps={this.state}`?

Answer (score 1):

I've been stuck on this forever. If you copy the params object via assign(), you can access them. It's a terrible solution, because you're then going to have to set state in that control anyway. React's main value is not having to do that.

I'm excited for someone to chastise me for this and post a much better solution.

```js
var copy = Object.assign({}, this.props.navigation.state);
console.log(copy.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aajiwani/react-navigation-aware-helper

You can try this, I have created to simplify this params problem.